# Unmarshalling to inner static class fields

Tags: java, jaxb, moxy

I have an entity class with a composite key that is a public static inner class of the entity. I would like to unmarshal a file and get the values into the fields of the inner class.

I tried several things with @XmlKey, @XmlPath, @XmlJoinNode but nothing worked and I'm not even sure I'm on the right way.

My xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<numbers>
    <one>one_text</one>
    <two>two_text</two>
    <three>three_text</three>
    <four>four_text</four>
</numbers>
```

My class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "numbers")
public class Numbers {

    public static class Id {

        @XmlElement
        private String one;

        @XmlElement
        private String two;

        public String getOne() {
            return one;
        }

        public void setOne(String one) {
            this.one = one;
        }

        public String getTwo() {
            return two;
        }

        public void setTwo(String two) {
            this.two = two;
        }
    }

    @XmlElement
    private String three;

    @XmlElement
    private String four;

    private Id id = new Id();

    public String getThree() {
        return three;
    }

    public void setThree(String three) {
        this.three = three;
    }

    public String getFour() {
        return four;
    }

    public void setFour(String four) {
        this.four = four;
    }

    public Id getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Id id) {
        this.id = id;
    }    
}
```

Don't worry about missing JPA annotations. Thanks for answers.

**update**

Precision : The XML file can't be modified, the java class could be if there is no way to keep things like this but it must be interpretable by hibernate as an entity with a composite primary key.

**solution using MOXy**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement(name = "numbers")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Entity
public class Numbers {

    @Embeddable
    public static class Id implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -2153062768685935342L;

        @Column
        @XmlElement
        private String one;

        @Column
        @XmlElement
        private String two;

        public String getOne() {
            return one;
        }

        public void setOne(String one) {
            this.one = one;
        }

        public String getTwo() {
            return two;
        }

        public void setTwo(String two) {
            this.two = two;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + ((one == null) ? 0 : one.hashCode());
            result = prime * result + ((two == null) ? 0 : two.hashCode());
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            Id other = (Id) obj;
            if (one == null) {
                if (other.one != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!one.equals(other.one))
                return false;
            if (two == null) {
                if (other.two != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!two.equals(other.two))
                return false;
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Column
    @XmlElement
    private String three;

    @Column
    @XmlElement
    private String four;

    @EmbeddedId
    @XmlPath(".")
    private Id id = new Id();


    public String getThree() {
        return three;
    }

    public void setThree(String three) {
        this.three = three;
    }


    public String getFour() {
        return four;
    }

    public void setFour(String four) {
        this.four = four;
    }

    public Id getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Id id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

**alternative to MOXy**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

@XmlRootElement(name = "numbers")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Entity
public class Numbers {

    @Embeddable
    public static class Id implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -2153062768685935342L;

        @Column
        private String one;

        @Column
        private String two;

        public String getOne() {
            return one;
        }

        public void setOne(String one) {
            this.one = one;
        }

        public String getTwo() {
            return two;
        }

        public void setTwo(String two) {
            this.two = two;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + ((one == null) ? 0 : one.hashCode());
            result = prime * result + ((two == null) ? 0 : two.hashCode());
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            Id other = (Id) obj;
            if (one == null) {
                if (other.one != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!one.equals(other.one))
                return false;
            if (two == null) {
                if (other.two != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!two.equals(other.two))
                return false;
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Column
    @XmlElement
    private String three;

    @Column
    @XmlElement
    private String four;

    @EmbeddedId
    @XmlTransient
    private Id id = new Id();


    public String getThree() {
        return three;
    }

    public void setThree(String three) {
        this.three = three;
    }


    public String getFour() {
        return four;
    }

    public void setFour(String four) {
        this.four = four;
    }

    public Id getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Id id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getOne() {
        return id.getOne();
    }

    public void setOne(String one) {
        id.setOne(one);
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getTwo() {
        return id.getTwo();
    }

    public void setTwo(String two) {
        id.setTwo(two);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your question is tagged [moxy] you could use MOXy's `@XmlPath` extension as follows to get the desired behaviour.

```
@XmlPath(".")
private Id id = new Id();
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using MOXy on this project and your solution is **exactly** what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The XML that can be (un)marshalled with your class Numbers is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<numbers>
  <three>tres</three>
  <four>quattro</four>
  <id>
    <one>uno</one>
    <two>due</two>
  </id>
</numbers>
```

This is Numbers, with some added annotations, omitting same as before:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "numbers")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Numbers {

    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public static class Id {
        @XmlElement
        private String one;
        @XmlElement
        private String two;
        // getters, setters
     }

    @XmlElement
    private String three;
    @XmlElement
    private String four;
    @XmlElement
    private Id id = new Id();
    // getters, setters
}
```

To achieve

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<numbers>
  <four>quattro</four>
  <one>uno</one>
  <three>tres</three>
  <two>due</two>
</numbers>
```

you can put all fields into Numbers:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "numbers")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Numbers {
    @XmlElement
    private String one;
    @XmlElement
    private String two;
    @XmlElement
    private String three;
    @XmlElement
    private String four;
    // getters, setters
}
```

Or you can delegate:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "numbers")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Numbers {

public static class Id {
    private String one;
    private String two;
    // getters, setters
}

private String three;
private String four;
private Id id = new Id();

@XmlElement
public String getThree() {
    return three;
}
public void setThree(String three) {
    this.three = three;
}
@XmlElement
public String getFour() {
    return four;
}
public void setFour(String four) {
    this.four = four;
}
@XmlTransient
public Id getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Id id) {
    this.id = id;
}    
@XmlElement
public String getOne() {
    return id.getOne();
}
public void setOne(String one) {
    id.setOne( one );
}
@XmlElement
public String getTwo() {
    return id.getTwo();
}
public void setTwo(String two) {
    id.setTwo( two );
}
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, the xml file structure must remain the same as posted. I would like to keep the class structure if possible but not obligatory.

Comment: Well, then forget the inner class and make one and two fields of Numbers. - Adding this to my answer.

Comment: My class is an entity with a composite PK. It can't be structured like this.

Comment: It *might* be possible to write an adapter from Number without inner class to NumberX with that inner class. But only if you really, really need it...

Comment: The delegate version doesn't seem to work. edit : I mean the one/two fields are still null.

Comment: For unmarshalling, you may have to ensure that Id id is set when the delegating setter is called. - What doesn't SEEM to work, and how?

Comment: The unmarshalling is done but one and two are still null (three and four are ok)

Comment: I made some tests, it worked like a charm. Thank you.